# Iterating through every path of a Trinomial Tree

Tags: lattice

I am attempting to come up with an algorithm to iterate through every possible path of a trinomial tree and am having difficulties coming up with one. Is there any literature on this or has anyone else written something similar?

To be specific I am trying to calculate the P&L of stock trades from node 0 to every possible path end.

EDIT: Let me clarify - for a 1 step trinomial tree there are three paths: 1 (up) 0 (middle) or -1 (down). Adding another step makes the tree have 5 ending points and 9 paths: 11 (up,up) 10 (up,mid) 01 (mid, up) 1-1 (up,down) 00 (mid,mid) -11 (down,up) 0-1 (m,d) -10 (d,m) -1-1 (d,d)

I am aware the total number of paths that end at a given point is given by Pascal's tetrahedron but I do not know how to come up with all the paths for an arbitrary (n-step) tree. So I need the 1,-1,1,-1,0 sequence which in this case would end on the middle node of a 5 step tree.

Comment: Like a depth-first search?

Comment: Can you describe the data structure of your tree? Is the tree recombining?

Comment: So you want to condition on a specific path end?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly, here's an example in Python. Any other programming language should be able to do something similar:

```
def search(path):
    if len(path) == 5:
        if sum(path) == 0:
            print path
    else:
        search(path+[1])
        search(path+[0])
        search(path+[-1])
```

Just invoke it with an empty array:

```
>> search([])
[1, 1, 0, -1, -1]
[1, 1, -1, 0, -1]
[1, 1, -1, -1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, -1, -1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, -1]
[1, 0, 0, -1, 0]
[1, 0, -1, 1, -1]
[1, 0, -1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, -1, -1, 1]
[1, -1, 1, 0, -1]
[1, -1, 1, -1, 0]
[1, -1, 0, 1, -1]
[1, -1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, -1, 0, -1, 1]
[1, -1, -1, 1, 0]
[1, -1, -1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, -1, -1]
[0, 1, 0, 0, -1]
[0, 1, 0, -1, 0]
[0, 1, -1, 1, -1]
[0, 1, -1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, -1, -1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, -1]
[0, 0, 1, -1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, -1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, -1, 1]
[0, 0, -1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, -1, 0, 1]
[0, -1, 1, 1, -1]
[0, -1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, -1, 1, -1, 1]
[0, -1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, -1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, -1, -1, 1, 1]
[-1, 1, 1, 0, -1]
[-1, 1, 1, -1, 0]
[-1, 1, 0, 1, -1]
[-1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[-1, 1, 0, -1, 1]
[-1, 1, -1, 1, 0]
[-1, 1, -1, 0, 1]
[-1, 0, 1, 1, -1]
[-1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[-1, 0, 1, -1, 1]
[-1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[-1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[-1, 0, -1, 1, 1]
[-1, -1, 1, 1, 0]
[-1, -1, 1, 0, 1]
[-1, -1, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Yea that looks like what I want I will extend it to loop through every possible ending point. I am not familiar with Python and can't seem to figure out what the statement path+[1] does. I am trying to implement this in c++ and it I am unsure how your code would do anything else besides add an element to an array with a 1 in it until there are 5 and then stop. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2183336 That Python notation is the *side-effect free* way of appending an element. Ie, it returns a new array without modifying the original. Again, the key point to my example is that this is a [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search); I recursively descend each possible path. The array notation I used in Python was just for convenience; the DFS is how I actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To convert an index to [base 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system) (actually to an array with the base 3 digits, each one selecting a move up/mid/down) you only need to alternate a modulo-3 (remainder) operator and integer division by 3.
Or were you asking for something else?